# catching double quotes inside word

Tags: regex, sed

How can properly catch words like this in sed ?
`text O"Neil text ...`

I've tried `'\w*\"\w*'` but apparently doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Use single quotes around the pattern. Instead of `\w`, try using `[[:alnum:]_]`.

Comment: I have single quotes

Comment: @bsd: Provide a sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
# cat File
aaaa
text O"Neil text
bbbb
cccc
```

Output:

```
# sed -n '/\w*"\w*/p' File
text O"Neil text
```

Or:

```
sed -n "/\w*\"\w*/p" File
```

Comment: forgot that `'-n`.